# How to make status bar and bottom navigation transparent in android using java in android studio?

Tags: java, android, transparent, android-fullscreen

I want to make my Activity as full screen with transparent status bar and transparent bottom navigation bar.

I used some code but there is some issues in the screenshot below. These is some space below the status bar and also above the bottom navigation. How to resolve that?. Please anyone help.

[image]

Comment: would be helpful if you share your code with us.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, there is simple code that just used to create an Activity with xml file. The xml's parent layout is match_parent and match_parent , height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two approaches:

Follow this documentation : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge(Don't forget to treat the insets of bottom for navigation bar and top padding for status bar to avoid view overflow)

Or just follow my example (that's work for me):

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Do this in the activity , to fit your screen in the screen boundary.
And after that you may need apply insets to bottom (for navigation bar) and to top (for status bar).

Comment: Thanks for your approaches. I will apply both and let you know.

Comment: I applied that but there is no solution.

Comment: what's the result? check if you are not to setting a theme behavior.

Comment: Do I needed to set different theme also?